# I want to query a table with two parameters in where condition and both the parameters are returned from another query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Want to query a table with two parameters in where condition and both the parameters are returned from another query.

Let us say a table t1 with column1 and column2,  if I use a query select column1,column2 from t1,suppose it return 10 records

I want to query something like below

```
for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
{
   select * 
   from t2 
   where t2.column1=t1.column1(jth position) 
     and t2.column2=t1.column2(jth position)
}
```

Comment: Sql server 2012

Comment: thanks for your effort

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to accomplish it. I like using embedded queries (SQL Server). I am not sure you can do this in other SQL languages (I've never tried).

```
select * 
from t2 
where 
    t2.column1 = (select column1 from t1 where t1.id = j)
    and t2.column2 = (select column2 from t1 where t1.id = j)
```

Please note you should look at this more like pseudo code. I made up a column `id` for the example but the point is that you do something like this, your embedded select statements must only return one result, not an array of results.

If you want to work with larger conditional data sets, you can use `joins` to accomplish the same thing:

```
select * 
from t2 
inner join t1 on t1.column1 = t2.column1
              and t1.column2 = t2.column2
```

Hope this helps.